# Ajax onClick Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, safari, mobile-safari

I have a custom WordPress plugin that uses a Javascript ajax onClick function to make a clickable element that rondomly selects an item from a dropdown list and then opens that selection in a new tab.

The code works like a dream on every desktop and mobile browser except Safari on iOS.

In Safari on iOS if you click the random button it succeeds in randomly selecting an option from the select list and shows the loading animation but it fails to load the new page from the selection.

It seems that this bug is similar to other safari only ajax onClick bugs that have been discussed at length since the early days of iOS. Except that I have yet to find a workaround to this particular implementation.

I'm including code for both the random button where the bug is found and the select list as, based on my research to date, it may be the interaction of these two elements that is causing the bug on Safari.

Any thoughts?

(The following code has been sanitized to protect my client)

### PHP in WordPress plugin

```html
            <div ><a  href="javascript:;" id="randoms" class="tooltip">
                <span class="tooltiptext" style="background : grey; opacity : 0.5;">Random</span>
            </a></div>
            <div class="select_able">
            <div class="ruler"></div>
            <img src="<?php echo CLIENT_WEBSITE_URL; ?>public/image/widget-background.jpg" alt="Widget">
                <select name="person_profile" id="person_id">
                    <option value="0" >Search</option>
                    <?php if(!empty($search_person)): ?>
                    <?php foreach($search_person as $search_person): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $search_person->entity_id; ?>"> <?php echo $search_person->person_name ?>  </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

### HTML Output

```html
            <div><a href="javascript:;" id="randoms" class="tooltip">
                <span class="tooltiptext" style="background : grey; opacity : 0.5;">Random</span>
            </a></div>
            <div class="select_able">
            <div class="ruler"></div>
            <img src="https://image.url" alt="Widget" data-pagespeed-url-hash="123456" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
                <select name="person_profile" id="person_id">
                    <option value="0">Search</option>
                    <!-- List with hundreds of options -->
                </select>
            </div>
```

### Javascript in WordPress plugin

```js
    $("#randoms").on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: ajaxUrl, 
        data: {
          action: "random_client"
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".loader").removeClass("hide");
        },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        success: function(resp) {
          $(".loader").addClass("hide");
          if (resp.code == 200) {
            var data = {
              id: resp.entity_id,
              text: resp.person_name
            };
            var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);
            $("#person_id")
              .append(newOption)
              .trigger("change");
            var pers_rating = $.trim($(".person_rating").val());
            if (pers_rating < 0) {
              $(".ruler").addClass("hide");
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });

    $(".new-tab-random").on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: {
          action: "random_client"
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".loader").removeClass("hide");
        },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        success: function(resp) {
          $(".loader").addClass("hide");
          if (resp.code == 200) {
            fetch_profile_tab(resp.entity_id, resp.person_name);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    $(".loader").removeClass("hide");
    $(document).on("click", ".lower", function() {
      $("#designator").val("lower");
      var designator = $("#designator").val();
      feed_back(designator);
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".higher", function() {
      $("#designator").val("higher");
      var designator = $("#designator").val();
      feed_back(designator);
    });

        function fetch_profile_tab(
      person_new_tab_id = 0,
      slug_name_new_tab = 0
    ) {
      var person_id;
      var slug_name;
      if (person_new_tab_id != 0) {
        person_id = person_new_tab_id;
        slug_name = string_to_slug(slug_name_new_tab);
      } else {
        person_id = $("#person_id").val();
        var data = $("#person_id").select2("data");
        slug_name = string_to_slug(data[0].text);
      }

      if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
        var new_link =
          window.location.origin +
          "/website/result/" +
          person_id;
      } else {
        var new_link =
          window.location.origin +  "/result/" + person_id;
      }

      window.open(new_link, "_blank");
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what part isn't working. The more details you give about your issue, the more likely we can help you with it.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier In Safari on iOS if you click the random button it succeeds in randomly selecting an option from the select list and shows the loading animation but it fails to load the new page from the selection.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to replace `href="javascript:;"` with `href="#"` in your `<a>` tag?

Comment: I had the same thought. Exact same behavior except that Safari loads the # link (taking you to the top of the page) before executing part of the JavaScript and, ultimately, failing to open the randomly selected option